# How to implement a window just like the quicktime player open file dialog in osx 10.10

Tags: macos, cocoa, window

Quicktime player open file dialog has no close/min/max button in the toolbar and at the same time, the dialog has the capacity to resize, I go through the cocoa interface build and try to set one window "style" like it, but haven't found one, I can set the window mask by using NSResizableWindowMask, but it will show the close/min/max button, I can hide these buttons but they will still occupy the space in toolbar even though they are hidden, so anyone know how to achieve the quick time player open file dialog's design?